# how can I run an exe with run as administrator in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, winium

I'm using winium driver to automate my desktop base application, and there is a scenario where I want to run my application as run as administrator. which I'm not able to perform.

Comment: Do you automatically start the app?

Comment: I suggest you to create a background service that runs as administrator and your test tells the service to start the app...